# How can I get the difference between values in a Pandas dataframe grouped by another field?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV of data I've loaded into a dataframe that I'm trying to massage:  I want to create a new column that contains the difference from one record to another, grouped by another field.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv'
all_counties = pd.read_csv(url, dtype={"fips": str})
all_counties.date = pd.to_datetime(all_counties.date)
oregon = all_counties.loc[all_counties['state'] == 'Oregon']

oregon.set_index('date', inplace=True)
oregon.sort_values('county', inplace=True)

# This is not working; I was hoping to find the differences from one day to another on a per-county basis
oregon['delta'] = oregon.groupby(['state','county'])['cases'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
oregon.tail()
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting results where the delta is always the same as the cases.

I'm new at Pandas and relatively inexperienced with Python, so bonus points if you can point me towards how to best read the documentation.

Comment: `.shift` only gives you the shifted value. I think you were gonna use [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets Try

```
oregon['delta']=oregon.groupby(['state','county'])['cases'].diff().fillna(0)
```